# Help With pattern matching

Tags: c#-2.0

In my code I have to match below 3 types of data

```
abcd:xyz:def
def:xyz
xyz:def
```

where "xyz" is the real data and other part are Junk data. Now, for first 2 types as below I can split with ':' and can get the array[1] position data ... which will give me the correct one.

```
abcd:xyz:def
def:xyz
```

I am not getting How can extract the 3rd case. Any idea? Please help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: What's your data type? String?

Comment: What distinguishes your real "xyz" data from the junk data?  Is it literally "xyz"?  Is the junk literally "abcd" or "def"? or is there an actual pattern to it?  What you have there is _not_ pattern matching with anything.

Comment: Do you have a way to know whether the good data is before or after the first colon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string case1 = "abcd:xyz:def";
string case2 = "def:xyz";
string case3 = "xyz:def";

string result1 = case1.Split(':')[1];
string result2 = case2.Split(':')[1];
string result3 = case3.Split(':')[0];
```

If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Marlon, your solution will work only when you know when you are encountering which type of pattern. Otherwise, 1st case is fine but what about the 2nd and 3rd ... both of them have same pattern ... data:data

Comment: @Rahul: If there is no way to know what good data looks like, then it's impossible to determine which case it fits.

Comment: Yes, that's what the same challenge I am facing. the data looks like "text:text:text" I mean on both the side of ':' it's plain text but what I know is that the correct data is either in middile in case of "data:data:data" or in 2nd place in case of "data:data" or in 1st place in case of "data:data" but my code going to encounter which case ... have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use array[0] instead of array[1] in the third case after splitting.

Comment: Nope, can't be done ... How will you know when your code ios going to encounter the 3rd case?

Comment: @Rahul: You'll need to go back and ask the question to whoever created the spec.

Comment: Hmm ... Yeah think you are correct. I have no way out. Thanks a lot everyone for your prompt response.